# Missing Git menu on right click

Tags: git

For some reason I dont know why I couldn't see this menu when I make a right click:

- Git Add all files now
- Git Commit Tool
- Git History
- Git Gui
- Git Branch
- Git Bash

What I have right now :

[image]

What I am looking for (inside the red rectangle) :

[image]

The softwares that I installed :

- Git-2.15.1.2-64-bit.exe
- TortoiseGit-2.5.0.0-64bit.msi
- GitExtensions-2.50.02-SetupComplete.msi

Comment: Have you contacted the software support?

Comment: No I didn't. Because I used the same software few months ago and it worked fine

Comment: Have you ever installed new version of Git for Windows?

Comment: Yes as you see on my description, I have install the latest version of Git (Git-2.15.1.2-64-bit.exe)

Comment: any solution for getting Git Branch menu back?